# Error converting data type nvarchar to date

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to execute a stored procedure that will take the start and end time from my DateTimePicker and check to see if a vehicle is available and return a dataset with those that are.  The code does work when I run it in SQL Managment Studio, so I am trying to execute with VBA in Visual studio.

I will plan to post later on help with displaying the dataset as I am not sure how to do this in code and have had a hard time finding good examples but for now I am trying to get past this error message.  I have gone back and changed the format to a custom format so it matches the date format in my SQL database. The custom format I am using on both datetimepickers is yyyy-MM-dd.  I have tried several of the suggestions on the various websites but no luck so far getting past this message.  Below is the code from my stored procedure as well as the visual basic code.

```
 CREATE PROC spVehicleAvailable
@RequestedStartDate Date,--DateTime selectedDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date
@RequestedEndDate Date--DateTime selectedDate = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date
AS
BEGIN
Select Vehicle.*
FROM Vehicle
        Where Vehicle.VehicleID NOT IN (
        SELECT VehicleID FROM LoanRequest
        WHERE @RequestedEndDate >= LoanRequest.StartDate 
        AND @RequestedStartDate <= LoanRequest.EndDate)  
        AND Available = 1   AND Scrap=0
    END;



Private Sub btnAvailable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAvailable.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlConnection1 As New SqlConnection("Data Source=GALE-PC1\SQLEXPRESS2012;Initial Catalog=VehicleCheckout;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "spVehicleAvailable"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedStartDate", Date.ParseExact(dtpStartDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestedEndDate", Date.ParseExact(dtpEndDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            'new code to try adding info into datagridview
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As New DataSet("Vehicles")  ' Not sure of this code
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters(0).Value = "Not-Sure" 'Not sure of this code
            da.Fill(ds)
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then
                MessageBox.Show("This Vehicle" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("SomethngElse").ToString) 'Not sure of this code
            End If
            'end new code
            sqlConnection1.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConnection1.Close()
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: try other dateformats like Date.ParseExact(dtpStartDate.Text, "dd-mm-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: I had tried several formats before posting here and was getting error messages. This custom format was the only one that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this : `Date.ParseExact(dtpStartDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in a imediate window, what's the result?

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this type of code so I am not sure what you are asking me to do.  I tried added the code so it is inside the sub where the form loads, but nothing happened so I am guessing I did not handle correctly, could you please provide more info.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio to devolop, you have a tool called "Imediate Window". You use this in debug mode. Put a break point in btnAvailable_Click function and write and execute the code: `Date.ParseExact(dtpStartDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for you know whtat is the result this convertion. In some cases, you need set a culture to work, but only with this result you will know if the convertion in VB.NET code is returning what you need.